# Statistical Physics of a System with Friction inside a Hot Bath

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, friction, hamiltonian-formalism

If you have a classical system (i.e obeying Newton's equations of motion) with Hamiltonian $H(x,p) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + U(x)$ then the statistical behaviour of this system is described by the probability density $e^{-\frac{\beta}{2}H}$, which can be used to find average quantities. If you want to model a system subject to friction in a hot bath without adding molecular details  than the Newtonian equations of motion change to $m\ddot{x} = F - \mu \dot{x} +R(t)$ where $R(t)$ is the random forcing term and $F$ is a conservative force. The flow given by this in the phase space does not conserve energy or phase space volume. How does one describe the statistical physics of such dynamics? What is the probability density one has to use? Grand canonical ensembles seems to deal with such stuff as well but I can not see how to formulate friction as such a system. Or what happens if you ignore $R(t)$ and write the system as "Hamiltonian" derived from a non-canonical change of variables? Can you just plugin the new Hamiltonian (without $R(t)$) to the usual partition function but integrate over the new variables? This doesnt seem right since without $R(t)$ the system would halt evantually, so $R(t)$ does have a critical role in this sense. Any keywords would be also welcome. For people who need a more concerete question I could ask how would you compute time average quantities of say a stochastic ODE like
$$
\dot{v} = kx - \mu v + R(t) ?
$$
Is there any partitian function like methods for this? Or just write the solutin and find average time integral if you can?

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is Leggett and Caldeira's 1983 paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378437183900134 and the field associated with it.

Comment: Do I really need to use a path integral formulation if I want to find time average quantities of a simple stochastic flow like $\dot{v} = kx - \mu v + R(t)$?

Comment: long story short: the friction changes nothing but timescales. Terms to google: Langevin Equation, Fokker-Planck-equation, Fluctuation-Dissipation-Theorem (Einstein-Smoluchowski-Relation)

Comment: @Bort: Are you saying that if I have a system of particles each with its own friction coefficient (not necessarily overdamped), the average quantities behave in the long run as if they were obeying $m\ddot{x} = F$?

Comment: no i saying that the fact that you assume a heat bath (so that equilibrium is given by boltzmann weights) necessarily introduces a friction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general and very hard question. As I understand it, you are asking about the steady state of a system where driving (through $R(t)$) an dissipation coexist. The answer depends on the statistics of $R(t)$. If you look up '[Einstein Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_%28kinetic_theory%29)', you will see how to relate the correlations of $R(t)$ to the dissipation coefficient $\mu$ in the case of a Gaussian white noise.

More general cases quickly become very difficult. And it is not always known if there exists a Hamiltonian formulation. A very general formalism for such stochastic differential equations is the Martin-Siggia-Rose formalism. This makes it possible to write a generating functional for the correlation functions of a stochastic classical field theory as a path integral weighted by a given action.

For example, adding such a stochastic driving to [Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations leads to modern research topic within the study of hydrodynamic turbulence.

I detailed how to compute averages in the case of a Gaussian white noise and when $k=0$ in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203693/langevin-equation-stochastic-differential-equation-what-are-the-subtleties/203853#203853) post. Generalising to $k\neq 0$ should not be hard.

Comment: I assume the simplest case where $R(t)$ is a Gaussian process with $0$ mean. Is the above claim that average quantities behave as if it was usual Newtonian mechanics $$\ddot{x}=F(x)$$ in the long run?

Comment: You never leave Newtonian mechanics. The dynamics are defined by Newton's equations. However if you compute average quantities, you must take into account the fluctuations of $R(t)$ carefully. $\langle x(t) \rangle'' = - k \langle x \rangle - \mu \langle x \rangle''$ as if $R(t)$ was not there, but $R(t)$ enters the computation of $\langle x(t) x(t') \rangle$ for example. Check out the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes but I meant newtonian mechanics with a conservative force=field that is derived from a potential that only depends on coordinate variables. Thanks for the link and the answer I will check if it is what I want.

Comment: One way to be sure that your dynamics are conservative is to choose every individual realisation of your stochastic process to be. If $\mu=0$ and the probability that $R(t)$ does not derives from a potential is zero, then your dynamics will be conservative by construction. If you are asking if effective conservative dynamics emerge once the random noise has been averaged over, then I don't know. This is a very hard problem and a modern research topic.

Comment: I see I am starting to understand the correct way to pose this question now thanks to your replies. I guess I should have asked does the time average of observables for the stoachastic ODE $\ddot{x} = -\nabla U(x) - \nu \dot{x} + R(t)$ converge to the statistical average of a system with Hamiltonian H = K + U via the equipartition theorem? Can you suggest some reading material on this?

Comment: @Sina Sorry, I can't think of some general book on the topic. As I said it's an open question. I learned about MSR formalism with the book of Zinn-Justin, [Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N8DBpTzBCJYC&dq=zinn+justin&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)., chapter 4. It is a very complete book about quantum field theory.

Comment: @Sina  The general theory of classical field theories coupled to thermal baths was worked out by Hohenberg and Halperin in [this](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.49.435) paper. It's a long, difficult and interesting to read. Learn about the Renormalisation Group first.

Comment: @Sina I recently read [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00912) and found it very interesting. You need to know about the Keldysh formalism though.